# Lint and old API level warning

Tags: android

I compile against Android 4.2 (API 17), in my Manifest I have:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
```

In code I use:

```
String first = sdf.format(new   Date(context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).firstInstallTime));
```

Field firstInstallTime was introduced in API 9.

Lint does not warn me, i.e. that this field is not valid in API 8. What am I missing, how should one detect this?

If I compile against Android 2.2 (API 8), I find the error and a bunch of extra errors due to new features used (> API 8) and the project won't compile.

(I'm aware of handling such things in runtime with for example Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)

What's the best way of working?

Why is lint not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This answer may be late but You should check your lint preferences

Right click on project -> Properties -> Android Lint Preferences

then search for min in the searchbox and select "UsesMinSDKAttributes"

Finally select "Include all" button.  Hopefully the check had just been surpressed (Something I've had to do just to fix a silly lint error)

Good luck.

Comment: This answer is based off eclipse rather than Android Studio. It may be similar in android studio.

Comment: Following this advice maybe I did something wrong, but now I have errors even in Google libraries and I can't find the way to restore the way Lint was before...

Comment: This answer is over 2 years old. The issue may still be the same but the method to fix it in Android studio has probably changed. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If it is intoduced in api level9 then try this.
     < uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

Comment: Yes, that would work. Maybe I was not clear, my point is how do I detected that I use methods/fields that are not supported in API 8? My understanding is that lint should report this? Or how should one handle it?

Comment: Hmm.... I use eclipse for development, and it definetly shows an error for this kind. But i can't tell you about lint.

Comment: I use eclipse for development and it definetly shows this type of error. But i cant tell you about lint. Moreover i dont think that changing target version would cause any effect. It is not a necessary attribute in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it will works when the https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56427 will be solved